# Google Analytics: track events for registered users

Tags: google-analytics

I'm pretty new to Google Analytics and analytics in general, so please bear with me. Right now I have a task to come up with desicion on what dev team need to integrate in order to track parameters like these:

- how many posts user creates in average per session / in specified period of time;
- how many users perform action X on their first session;
- percentage of active / inactive users for X period of time.

And many others along those line. As far as I'm concerned dev team uses a handful of events right now in their code. So I thought it is possible to use `USER-ID` feature to track some interactions for registered members, but I don't know how to calculate average values from that. In fact, I'm not sure if we need `USER-ID` at all, although I assume we do as we would like to track activities accross different devices. Maybe we can employ Custom Variables somehow here? In any case, any hint or general idea would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

NOTE: I'm aware of Google Analytics' terms of service and we are not going to store any of forbidden data, we just need to do some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve data for your list you need to send Analytics both a user-level custom dimension (such as the user-id) and a session-level custom dimension.
I mean that if you use clientId (cid) as custom dimension at the user level and a value like timestamp as custom dimension at the session level you can know what is the first session of an user (which is a basis on which you can respond to some of your questions).
If you want track the cross-device you must also pass the userId as custom dimension at the user level (however this will be applied only to users who have logged in)..

Averages will be calculated directly by Analytics (in the panel or via API) when you view those custom dimensions.
For example with a query that questions together: sessions, the custom dimension like clientId (user level) and the custom dimension like timestamp (sessionID).
Then based on the calculations you need to do you can export the data and work it on Excel.

Comment: Pardon me for such a long delay. Thank you for your answer, but can you possibly provide some context to it? My knowledge on the subject are modest at best, so it's hard to understand how exactly two custom dimensions of user and session scopes will get the job done. As I see it, user-level dimension allows to calculate approximate amount of registered users for the time range (no cross-device data?), whereas session-level is used for what? Can you post your suggestions as an update to post? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you, with the context you've provided your answer has become a lot easier for a newbie like me to understand it. Although there still will be things I need to figure out with the list of requirments I have, your answer explains a lot of what I need. Thank you.